# UI Design Query : VF vs JS frameworks/libs like Angular,jQuery

Tags: visualforce, jquery, design, ui

Our team is a much younger team with only a few yrs of exp in SF.
Recently SF informed us via mail that they will be removing/modifying the home page component code written HTML/JS and recommended us to use VF Area.

This change of theirs impacted us *but not significantly though*.

I started to have this nagging doubt in my mind with respect to their commitment for supporting jQuery or JS based frameworks for UI development.

In our upcoming module, us devs, decided for a change to build as much as possible all the UI functionality in jQuery and leveraging existing jQuery plugins.

But if we do that, then a couple of releases down from today whats stopping Salesforce to issue a release alert (*like how we got one today)* stating that they no longer support jQuery and asking us to rewrite everything in VF ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The update removes an area *where* code was previously allowed to run, not *what* code is allowed to run. Salesforce can't (and won't), bar a particular library, because they'd have to bar JavaScript completely, which would make all future mobile development, all future Visualforce, etc, completely inert and useless. Salesforce is simply trying to reduce the possibility of bad code compromising the core UI through "hacks". Requiring Visualforce sidebar components allows the code to be isolated in a safe way, while still allowing approved UI modifications and sidebar features.